# How to enable mouse in Putty in Windows?

Tags: windows, mouse, putty

I installed Putty+Bitvise in Windows and can connect to local computer.
Mouse clicks in Midnight Commander won't however work.
MC in Putty for Linux machine can respond to mouse clicks on the other hand.
What am I missing?